# Calling BLAS functions

Tags: fortran, blas

Here is a simple program

```
PROGRAM MAIN
implicit none
integer, PARAMETER :: N=10
real*8 :: A(N)
real*8 :: x=0.1D0
integer :: i=1
Do i=1,N
A(i)=i
end do
call dscal(N,x, A, 1)

x=dasum(N,A,1)

END PROGRAM MAIN
```

I compile with the command

```
gfortran   test.f90  -o test -O1  -I /usr/include/ -L /usr/lib  -lblas
```

While I have no problem calling the subroutine `dscal` I get the following error for the function `dasum`

> ```
> test.f90:15.2:
>
> x=dasum(N,A,1)
> 1
> Error: Function 'dasum' at (1) has no IMPLICIT type
> ```

Should I include a certain file to define the BLAS functions?

Comment: Which BLAS implementation do you use?  Vendors often provide interfaces in modules for the procedures.

Comment: @francescalus `libblas.so.3` is the library linked in the executable when it compiles correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For functions, you need to manually specify the return value (and if you are feeling posh, optionally an `external`):

```
real*8,external :: dasum
```

---

Additionally, please don't use `real*8`. It is not Standard-conforming, not portable and quite confusing. Instead use the `kind` parameter to define the precision, e.g.:

```
real(kind=kind(1.d0))
```

or the like. If you can use the `ISO_Fortran_env module`, use its constants `REAL32` and `REAL64`.

Comment: Should I specify manually the return values for all BLAS/LAPACK functions I use? Isn't there some file that contains these definitions?

Comment: In principle, yes. However, some implementations provide modules you can `use` for that purpose. MKL provides [include files](https://software.intel.com/de-de/node/468384#3220B6B9-8A35-42E6-888D-8832E65C2EDB).