# BLAS function returns zero in Fortran90

Tags: fortran, fortran90, blas, openblas

I am learning to use BLAS in Fortran90, and wrote a simple program using the subroutine [SAXPY](https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl-developer-reference-fortran-axpy) and the function [SNRM2](https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl-developer-reference-fortran-nrm2). The program computes the distance between two points by subtracting one vector from the other, then taking the euclidean norm of the result.

I am specifying the return value of SNRM2 as `external` according to the answer to a similar question, ["Calling BLAS functions"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36338770/calling-blas-functions). 
My full program:

```
program test
implicit none

real :: dist
real, dimension(3) :: a, b
real, external :: SNRM2

a = (/ 3.0, 0.0, 0.0 /)
b = (/ 0.0, 4.0, 0.0 /)

call SAXPY(3, -1.0, a,1, b,1)
print *, 'difference vector: ', b

dist = 6.66  !to show that SNRM2 is doing something
dist = SNRM2(3, b, 1) 
print *, 'length of diff vector: ', dist

end program test
```

The result of the program is:

```
difference vector:   -3.00000000       4.00000000       0.00000000    
length of diff vector:    0.00000000
```

The difference vector is correct, but the length ought to be 5. So why is SNRM2 returning a value of zero?

---

I know the variable `dist` is modified by SNRM2, so I don't suspect my openBLAS installation is broken. I'm running macos10.13 and installed everything with homebrew.

I am compiling with gfortran with many flags enabled, and I get no warnings:

```
gfortran test.f90 -lblas -g -fimplicit-none -fcheck=all -fwhole-file -fcheck=all -fbacktrace -Wall -Wextra -Wline-truncation -Wcharacter-truncation -Wsurprising -Waliasing -Wconversion -Wno-unused-parameter -pedantic -o test
```

I tried looking at [the code for snrm2.f](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/df/d28/group__single__blas__level1_ga35c2ec0e9bfdaa545320c2a134fcc471.html#ga35c2ec0e9bfdaa545320c2a134fcc471), but I don't see any potential problems.

I also tried declaring my variables with `real(4)` or `real(selected_real_kind(6))` with no change in behavior.

Thanks!

Comment: Mhm, works on my machine with the latest OpenBLAS. Maybe something is wrong with your installation...

Comment: Thanks for trying it out! I installed everything using homebrew on macos 10.13. I ran `brew doctor` and `brew update` just fine... 

My computer was provided by my institute with some software preinstalled. Could multiple instances of BLAS be a problem? If so, how would I look for them in my system or change them?

Comment: TIO gives dist = 5, https://tio.run/##bZG7TsMwFIb38xQ/nRLkXtKgDpUYeAAQogtMkZ26qSXHjmxTeHqCEwclA4t1zv@duy/WBcfNurkko@87ZxvHWwTpA316CeVtNdFKmhupttOqVgHGGknkJNc4HnFWMX5wWDRbabyyJivzAXEGMSH5HaQzKeP08va8J@qcMgH3DLVtO6Wlq27Sjdk5Eccjsi3KzY5hNz3Y5iSSPkoPC51qrjVOT@@vH1nJsC4GxlkRJ2BFPvdaDYVXES0kkSRBNOwSncPmcADugoW/2i@EKw9p6HgTnK0yDbxtZbhG6y9n5ENrwVDkoP/qz5Kxrt1nEMgTm/1F0FR5xdKNSZozlr/U9z/1RfPG92stNPe/ but gfortran-8.1 on OSX10.11 (installed via Homebrew, on my mac) gives dist = 0.0 ...

Comment: As you "have" the code of snrm2.f just add it temporary to your project under a different name and see what happens. Same you can do with saxpy. You can also disable at that moment optimization etc.

Comment: For anyone coming to this question, an explanation of the issue with `snrm2` on Mac is given here: https://fortran-lang.discourse.group/t/how-many-blas-libraries-have-this-error/4454.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this [page](http://grokbase.com/t/r/r-sig-mac/106pkkknqd/problems-with-single-precision-routines-in-64-bit-veclib-blas), there seems to be some issue with single precision routines in the BLAS shipped with Apple's Accelerate Framework. 
On my Mac (OSX10.11), gfortran-8.1 (installed via Homebrew) + default BLAS (in the system) gives a wrong result:

```
$ gfortran-8 test.f90 -lblas
or
$ gfortran-8 test.f90 -L/System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/Current/ -lBLAS
$ ./a.out
 difference vector:   -3.00000000       4.00000000       0.00000000    
 length of diff vector:    0.00000000
```

while explicitly linking with OpenBLAS (installed via Homebrew) gives the correct result:

```
$ gfortran-8 test.f90 -L/usr/local/Cellar/openblas/0.2.20_2/lib -lblas
$ ./a.out
 difference vector:   -3.00000000       4.00000000       0.00000000    
 length of diff vector:    5.00000000
```

The above page suggests that the problem occurs when linking with the system BLAS in a way that is not compliant with the old g77 style. Indeed, attaching `-ff2c` option gives the correct result:

```
$ gfortran-8 -ff2c test.f90 -lblas
$ ./a.out
 difference vector:   -3.00000000       4.00000000       0.00000000    
 length of diff vector:    5.00000000
```

But I guess it may be better to use the latest OpenBLAS (than using `-ff2c` option) ...

---

The following is a separate test in C (to check that the problem is not specific to gfortran).

```
// test.c
#include <stdio.h>
float snrm2_( int*, float*, int* );

int main()
{
    float b[3] = { -3.0f, 4.0f, 0.0f };
    int n = 3, inc = 1;

    float dist = snrm2_( &n, b, &inc );

    printf( "b = %10.7f %10.7f %10.7f\n", b[0], b[1], b[2] );
    printf( "dist = %10.7f\n", dist );
    return 0;
}

$ gcc-8 test.c -lblas
$ ./a.out
b = -3.0000000  4.0000000  0.0000000
dist =  0.0000000

$ gcc-8 test.c -lblas -L/usr/local/Cellar/openblas/0.2.20_2/lib
$ ./a.out
b = -3.0000000  4.0000000  0.0000000
dist =  5.0000000
```

As far as I've tried, the double-precision version (DNRM2) works even with the system BLAS, so the problem seems only with the single-precision version (as suggested in the above page).